# Normalizer of a reflection supgroup of a finite complex reflection group

Tags: gr.group-theory, reflection-groups

Let $W \leq \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}^\ell)$ be a finite complex reflection group acting on the finite dimensional complex vectorspace $\mathbb{C}^\ell$.
Let $W' \leq W$ be a reflection subgroup, i.e. a subgroup generated by reflections.

Under which condition is the normalizer $N_W(W') \leq W'$ itself a complex reflection group?
Is there any reference which I can take a look at?

For example if $W = G_{31}$ (Shephard-Todd-Classification) and $W' = G(4,4,4) \leq W$ then $N_W(W')\cong G(4,2,4)$.

Comment: For the case where W is a real reflection group and W' is a parabolic subgroup then the structure of the normaliser was completely determined in a paper of Howlett. See "Normalisers of parabolic subgroups of reflection groups", J. London Math. Soc. (2), vol 21 (1980).